# MediaWiki: How to delete the about page?

Tags: php, javascript, css, mediawiki

in a MediaWiki project I don't need the automatically created **About** webpage because in this case the homepage already covers the about **details** of the project.

I can delete any webpage but for some reason I cannot delete the About webpage,
there is no **Delete button** in the About webpage as there is for basically any other webpage in MediaWiki.

How could I safely delete the About webpage itself?

---

### Update for Tgr

Sadly, I cannot remove the link from MediaWiki:Sidebar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatically created About page. A link to it does get created automatically, you can remove that by editing `MediaWiki:Sidebar`.

Comment: Thank you, in Hebrew it was: `index.php?title=מדיה_ויקי:Sidebar&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop`.

Comment: Seems I cannot delete it from there (please see update in question).

Comment: You have to be logged in as an administrator.

Comment: My user is a bureaucrat, Sysop and interface-editor, as long is the first user created. From the documentation I understand this is indeed an "administrator" (due to Sysop).

Comment: I can't read Hebrew, but there's a cursor in that screenshot so presumably the page is editable.

Comment: Yes but I can't see any child there like "About" (אודות), nor can I see "Privacy policy" (מדיניות הפרטיות).